# convertir codigo c# a javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

tengo este codigo y deseo repetir lo mismo pero en javascript lo que es la consulta
model.grafico.... ese queria saber como pasarlo

```
 var data = string.Empty;

 foreach (var grafico in Model.Grafico.Where(grafico => !data.Contains(grafico.Mes+" "+grafico.Anho)))
 {
   data += "{ 'Mes':'" + grafico.Mes+" "+grafico.Anho + "'";
   data = Model.Grafico.Where(fila => fila.Mes == grafico.Mes).Aggregate(data, (current, fila) => current +(", '" + fila.Rubro + "' : '" + fila.Monto + "'"));
   data += "},";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 let data = '';
 const graficos = Model.Grafico.filter(grafico => data.indexOf(grafico.Mes + " " + grafico.Anho) == -1);

 graficos.forEach(grafico => {
   data += "{ 'Mes':'" + grafico.Mes + " " + grafico.Anho + "'";
   data = Model.Grafico
     .filter(fila => fila.Mes == grafico.Mes)
     .reduce((acc, fila) => acc + (", '" + fila.Rubro + "' : '" + fila.Monto + "'"), data);
   data += "},";
 });
```

Comment: Gracias funciono perfecto!!!!

Comment: pues marca la respuesta como aceptada porfavor.